# Vertical scrolling (or visibleItemsInvalidationHandler) resets the inner offset of the orthogonal section with groupPagingCentered

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, orthogonal, custom-scrolling, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I did UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout with orthogonal section with groupPagingCentered as follow:

```
func neighborsRealitiesSection() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
  let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
  let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    
  let cellWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3 + 1
  let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(cellWidth), heightDimension: .absolute(cellWidth))
  let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    
  let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
  section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
    
  section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { items, offset, environment in
    items.filter { $0.representedElementKind != UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader }.forEach { item in
      let distanceFromCenter = abs((item.frame.midX - offset.x) - environment.container.contentSize.width / 2.0)
      let minScale: CGFloat = 0.7
      let maxScale: CGFloat = 1
      let scale = max(maxScale - (distanceFromCenter / environment.container.contentSize.width), minScale)
        
      item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scale: scale)
    }
  }
}
```

The other sections are scrolled vertically. When scrolling vertically, the orthogonal offset is reset to zero. If I comment on the visibleItemsInvalidationHandler, it will not be reset.

Why does it happen? Does anybody have this problem?

Comment: Exactly the same happens to me. However it's buggy even without `visibleItemsInvalidationHandler`. Looks like `groupPagingCentered` is really buggy right now. Did you manage to fix the issue somehow?

Comment: @StasIvanov, unfortunately, no. I didn't go back to it anymore.

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  Anyone find a work around or fix to this?

Comment: @Rob, hi.
I couldn't get what I wanted this way, but you can have a look at [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057985/adding-contentinset-to-the-orthogonalscrollingbehavior-section-causes-the-penult). It gives the same result, but works if the cell takes up more than half of the screen.